# How can I add 'path' to my Artifactory AQL query?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm using insomnia to make calls to the Artifactory API.
I have the following query, which works really well:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"my-repository-virt"}}, {"$and":[{"@my.fileType":{"$match": "jar"}},{"@my.otherType":{"$match": "type2"}},{"@prodVersion":{"$match": "false"}}]})
```

But I have a problem in that there are duplicate files in some sub-folders with the same properties/filename that I would like to exclude.
I would like to add path to this query, but I can never get any results returned.
The repository is a virtual repository that links to 3 other real repositories.

One of my colleagues can call the following query with the command line tool and get the expected results:

```
 jfrog rt search my-repo-snapshots/myproject/subfolder/jars/*.jar
```

I have tried adding the path parameter to my query, I've tried removing everything except the repo and the path, like this:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"my-repo-snapshots"}},{"path" : "my-repo-snapshots/myproject/subfolder/jars/*.jar"})
```

I've tried with just the path, with variations on the path, including/excluding the repo name, using the virtual repo, the actual repo, but I always get a successful search with 0 results returned.

How can I build this query to search the virtual repo, along a certain path, and including certain properties?

EDIT:
I've also tried:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"my-repo-snapshots"}},{"path" : {"$match":"my-repo-snapshots/myproject/subfolder/jars/*.jar"}})
```

Both with the repo in the path and without, I still get 0 results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I figured it out.
The `path` part needs to be added in with the `{"$and": ...}` section where the properties are included. Like so:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"my-repository-virt"}}, 
{"$and":[
{"path":{"$match":"path/to/relevant/folders/*"}}, 
{"@my.fileType":{"$match": "jar"}},
{"@my.otherType":{"$match": "type2"}},
{"@prodVersion":{"$match": "false"}}
]})
```

Comment: Note that path match expression should not include the repository as first path item, eventhough the repository is shown as part of the path in the results (at least for docker).

Answer (score 2):

The easier fix would have been:

```
items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"my-repo-snapshots"}},{"path" : {"$eq":"my-repo-snapshots/myproject/subfolder/jars"}, {"name" : {"$match":"*.jar"}})
```

So the problem with your initial attempt, is that the "path" should match the folder and the "name" should match the filename